# Efficiently counting numbers falling within each range of numbers

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, data.table, mapply

I'm looking for a faster solution to the problem below. I'll illustrate the problem with a small example and then provide the code to simulate a large data as that's the point of this question. My actual problem size is of list length = 1 million entries.

Say, I've two lists as shown below:

```
x <- list(c(82, 18), c(35, 50, 15))
y <- list(c(1,2,3,55,90), c(37,38,95))
```

#### Properties of x and y:

- Each element of the list `x` always sums up to 100.
- Each element of `y` will always be sorted and will be always between 1 and 100.

#### The problem:

Now, what I'd like is this. Taking `x[[1]]` and `y[[1]]`, I'd like to find the count of numbers in `y[[1]]` that are 1) <= 82 and 2) > 82 and <= 100. That would be, c(4, 1) because numbers <= 82 are `c(1,2,3,55)` and number between 83 and 100 is `c(90)`. Similarly for `x[[2]]` and `y[[2]]`, c(0, 2, 1). That is, the answer should be:

```
[[1]]
[1] 4 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 2 1
```

Let me know if this is still unclear.

---

#### Simulated data with 1 million entries

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 100
n <- 1e6
len <- sample(2:3, n, TRUE)

x <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(ix) {
    probs <- sample(100:1000, len[ix])
    probs <- probs/sum(probs)

    oo <- round(N * probs)
    if (sum(oo) != 100) {
        oo[1] <- oo[1] + (100 - sum(oo))
    }
    oo
})

require(data.table)
ss <- sample(1:10, n, TRUE)
dt <- data.table(val=sample(1:N, sum(ss), TRUE), grp=rep(seq_len(n), ss))
setkey(dt, grp, val)
y <- dt[, list(list(val)),by=grp]$V1
```

---

#### What I've done so far:

Using `mapply` (slow):

I thought of using `rank` with `ties.method="first"` and `mapply` (obvious choice with 2 lists) first and tried out this:

```
tt1 <- mapply(y, x, FUN=function(a,b) { 
    tt <- rank(c(a, cumsum(b)), ties="first")[-(1:length(a))]; c(tt[1]-1, diff(tt)-1)
})
```

Although this works just fine, it takes a lot of time on 1M entries. I think the overhead of computing `rank` and `diff` that many times adds to it. This takes **241 seconds**!

Therefore, I decided to try and overcome the usage of `rank` and `diff` by using `data.table` and sorting with a "group" column. I came up with a longer but **much faster** solution shown below:

Using `data.table` (faster):

```
xl <- sapply(x, length)
yl <- sapply(y, length)
xdt <- data.table(val=unlist(x, use.names=FALSE), grp=rep(seq_along(xl), xl), type = "x")
xdt[, cumval := cumsum(val), by=grp]
ydt <- data.table(val=unlist(y, use.names=FALSE), grp=rep(seq_along(yl), yl), type = "y")
tt2 <-rbindlist(list(ydt, xdt[, list(cumval, grp, type)]))
setkey(tt2, grp, val)
xdt.pos <- which(tt2$type == "x")
tt2[, type.x := 0L][xdt.pos, type.x := xdt.pos]
tt2 <- tt2[xdt.pos][tt2[, .N, by = grp][, N := cumsum(c(0, head(N, -1)))]][, sub := type.x - N]
tt2[, val := xdt$val]

# time consuming step
tt2 <- tt2[, c(sub[1]-1, sub[2:.N] - sub[1:(.N-1)] - 1), by = grp]
tt2 <- tt2[, list(list(V1)),by=grp]$V1
```

This takes **26 seconds**. So it's about 9 times faster. I'm wondering if it's possible to get much more speedup as I'll have to recursively compute this on 5-10 such 1 million elements. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something like `hist(y[[k]],breaks=c(x[[k]][1:(n-1)],100) )`  ?

Comment: Carl, what's k, 1 to 1e6? Gives an error for k=2 on the big data.

Comment: in the example: c(0, 2, 1), where does 0 come from? i think 2 = {<=50}; 1 = { >50}

Comment: @ZoltánNagy, the counts in y for x between 1-35, 36-85, 86-100.

Comment: Arun, you've got two list variables.  Since you're matching `x[[1]]` against `y[[1]]`, `x[[2]]` against `y[[2]]`,  I assumed you always matched up like that.  What are your values in your real dataset for `x[[2]]` and  `y[[2]]` ?  If they're of length 1, then possibly `hist` will fail.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I can't imagine `hist` being faster than e.g. `findInterval` and `findInterval` is slower than `data.table` here

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, the minimum length of elements in x is 2 and the minimum length of elements in y is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another `data.table` approach. **Edit** I added a (dirty?) hack that speeds this up and makes it ~2x faster than the OP `data.table` solution.

```
# compile the data.table's, set appropriate keys
xl <- sapply(x, length)
yl <- sapply(y, length)
xdt <- data.table(val=unlist(x, use.names=FALSE), grp=rep(seq_along(xl), xl))
xdt[, cumval := cumsum(val), by=grp]
ydt <- data.table(val=unlist(y, use.names=FALSE), grp=rep(seq_along(yl), yl))

# hack #0, set key but prevent sorting, since we know data is already sorted
setattr(ydt, 'sorted', c('grp', 'val'))

# by setting the key in y to val and in x to cumval we can
# leverage the rolling joins
setattr(xdt, 'sorted', c('grp', 'cumval'))  # hack #1 set key, but prevent sorting
vals = xdt[, cumval.copy := cumval][ydt, roll = -Inf]

# hack #2, same deal as above
# we know that the order of cumval and cumval.copy is the same
# so let's convince data.table in that
setattr(vals, 'sorted', c('grp', 'cumval.copy'))

# compute the counts and fill in the missing 0's
# for when there is no y in the appropriate x interval
tt2 = vals[, .N, keyby = list(grp, cumval.copy)][xdt][is.na(N), N := 0L]

# convert to list
tt2 = tt2[order(grp, cumval.copy), list(list(N)), by = grp]$V1
```

Comment: I should probably mention that I was testing on a slightly smaller set with n = 1e5, since my machine was dying at 1e6.

Comment: @Arun, actually I just tested 1e6 on a different machine and the numbers were 39s OP vs 19s this (using sapply's in both versions)

Answer (score 0):

This is about 25% faster but outputs as a matrix rather than a list. You many be able to use appy/sappy to make it work with a list (saving as a list was slowing it down).

```
c=matrix(0,length(x),100)
for(j in 1:length(x)){
  a=-1
  b=0
  for(i in 1:length(x[[j]])){
    a=b
    b=b+x[[j]][i]
    c[j,i]=sum((a<=y[[j]])*(y[[j]]<=b))
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you just doing histogram binning the long way?